# The adjoint of matrix operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

I have a 2 by 2 matrix as follows:
$$
A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
d &0\\
-c& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $d$ $c$ are two constant. Then the [paper](http://tuomov.iki.fi/mathematics/jumpset.pdf) I am reading, page 21, after equation $(5.3)$ claiming that 
$$\tag 1
[A]^* A=
\begin{bmatrix}
d^2+c^2 &-c\\
-c& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I am keeping getting
$$
[A]^* A=
\begin{bmatrix}
d &0\\
0& d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(where by $[A]^\ast$ we denote the adjoint)

Can anybody help me to figure how could I get $(1)$ as above?

Thank you!

PS: I got 
$$
[A]^*=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0\\
c& d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You might be using the adjugate (sometimes called the "classical adjoint").

Comment: The adjoint the paper is referring to is likely the conjugate transpose, so just the transpose if $A$ is real.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I got confursed with cofactor matrix. Thx!

Comment: I believe your adjoint is wrong as all you need to do (provided c is real) is just switch it with he zero entry